# How to access data in documents from realtime listener python

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

Apologies if some of this doesn't make sense, I'm struggling to understand realtime listeners completely.

I'm trying to add a realtime listener to the chat part of my app, so I can add new messages to the screen as they come into the database. In the below code I load all current messages to the screen when the user opens the page and then I (try to) add the realtime listener in so any new messages can be added to the screen.

However, the `doc_snapshot` is just a list of the document ids, rather than the `message_dict` I have been using above, how do I access the data for each document in `doc_snapshot`, rather than just the id?

Or am I doing it completely wrong, should I not load do a one-time load of the messages when the screen is opened and just use a realtime listener to load the messages and listen for new messages?

`self.local_id` is the id of the user who has logged in, `doc_id` is the id of the person they're messaging.

```
    def move_to_chat(self, doc_id):
        group_id = self.local_id + ":"+ doc_id
        doc_ref = self.my_firestore.db.collection(u'messages').document(group_id)
        doc = doc_ref.get()
        if doc.exists: # Check if the document exists. If it does, load the messages to the screen
            get_messages = self.my_firestore.db.collection(u'messages').document(group_id).collection(group_id).order_by(u'Timestamp').limit(20)
            messages = get_messages.stream()
            for message in messages:
                message_dict = message.to_dict()
                try:
                    if message_dict['IdFrom'] == self.local_id:
                        #Add label to left of screen
                    else:
                        #Add label to right of screen
                except:
                    pass
        else: # If it doesn't, create it
            self.my_firestore.db.collection(u'messages').document(group_id).set({
                u'GroupId': group_id
            })
            add_to_doc = self.my_firestore.db.collection(u'messages').document(group_id).collection(group_id).document()
            add_to_doc.set({
                u'Timestamp': datetime.datetime.now()
            })

        # Watch for new messages
        self.query_watch = self.my_firestore.db.collection(u'messages').document(group_id).collection(group_id)
        # Watch the document
        self.query_watch.on_snapshot(self.on_snapshot)

    def on_snapshot(self, doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
        for doc in doc_snapshot:
            #Here's where I'd like to access data from the documents, to find the message that has been added.
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google Firestore [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/document.html) for Snapshot method explained the Classes for representing documents for the Google Cloud Firestore API.You can refer to this document to conform the returning values.